# Evaluate the performance for different parameter of a function

Tags: python, performance, computer-science

I want to know how a set of parameters affect the performance of a function `f`.
I do this to store the execute time of the parameters:

```
ListOfParam=[param1,param2,param3]
Time=[]
for param in ListOfParam:
    start=time.time()
    f(param) 
    end=time.time()
    Time.append(end-start)
```

I am now worrying about whether execution of `param1` will affect execution 
 time of `param2`, because some `param` would use multiple CPUs of my computer. How to make it fair for all the `param`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `timeit` Python module. You can read the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), and look the examples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#examples). Is better to use this module than implement you own timer, because `timeit` handle:

- the Garbage Collector of Python to prevent that process from skewing the results by scheduling a collection run at an inopportune moment.
- it picks the most accurate timer for your OS, `time.time` or `time.clock`.
- it repeats the tests many times to eliminate the influence of other tasks on your machine, such as disk flushing and OS scheduling.

Plus: `IPython` include the `%timeit` magic function for this purposes ([source](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit)).